# cannot load library libcairo

Tags: python, django, cairo, weasyprint

I have problem when trying to run a website in Django:

```
OSError: no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
cannot load library 'libcairo.so': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': libcairo.2.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': libcairo-2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Althought the package is installed.

I have installed weasyprint

```
pip3 install weasyprint

python -m pip install WeasyPrint




  sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libffi-dev shared-mime-info
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev
sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev
```

I have Lubuntu system.
Any ideas how can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install everything, that is mentioned in the docs: https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#debian-ubuntu

Comment: yes, I did (if the commend they wrote install all of necessary packages)

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing weasyprint after installing libcairo. Also, `undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var` error may indicate some conflict with `freetype` package - is custom freetype-xxx installed?

Comment: Your fontconfig was build against a newer version of freetype, but somehow ends up being loaded with an older version of freetype, hence the undefined version. Either, there is another `libfreetype.so` somewhere, or you replaced your `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so` with an older version and everything is broken.

Comment: Running `nm -DS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*freetype.so | grep FT_Done` can tell you if there is a `FT_Done_MM_Var` function in there. (There are other functions that begin with `FT_Done` - this is only there to ensure things work correctly, e.g. you should always see `FT_Done_Face` in the output.)

Comment: Sorry for answering late- recenlty I had no time to finish my installation. I have reinstalled WeasyPrint. I have no freetype package (at least not listed by `pip list`). I also see `FT_Done_MM_Var` function after typing `nm -DS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*freetype.so | grep FT_Done`. The error is still the same

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For Ubuntu 20 and Debian based distro, try:**

```
sudo apt-get install libpangocairo-1.0-0
```

Comment: Worked for me..Thanks..!!!. Can you explain the problem?

Comment: @basharpazhedath, really I don't have obviously a great cause about it,  we just install a missed package which is the Pango library (for the layout and rendering of text, font handling for GTK+)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove `libfreetype.so.6` file from `home/user/anaconda3/envs/myvenv/lib` directory (idea taken from https://kb.tecplot.com/2019/09/11/undefined-symbol-ft_done_mm_var/)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here that is getting the error:

```
/lib/x86_84-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
```

Run the command:

```
sudo find / -name *freetype*
```

As Uli Schlachter mentioned it's due to fonts being built in a newer version and used in an older version.
I used alis01's comment to find out that for me:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfreetype.so.6
```

was causing the issue. I renamed it to libfreetype.so.6.bak and all has been well since.